# How is spring able to inject the proper bean using the parameter name?

Tags: java, spring

In the following body of a class annotated with `@Configuration`, the factory method `concat` is called with the right beans using the parameter names. Those names are not available via reflection without parameters options (jdk8) or debug info. How does spring get that information at runtime?

```java
@Bean
String data01 () {
    return "data01-text";
}
@Bean
String data02 () {
    return "data02-text";
}
@Bean
String concat (String data01, String data02) {
    return data01 + "-" + data02;
}
```

Comment: There is an error in my question, debug information is available by default. Therefore, spring takes it from there.